# Keep the same position for images with different width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a photo gallery in my website...The photos are in dialog with next,prev,close buttons. Each next/prev event I load a new image into the dialog...Photos have a different width-How can I load the pictures at the same position? I mean because the pictures are with different width the position of the images is changing...

Comment: so you want the top left corner to remain in the same absolute position of the viewport?

Comment: Might be easier for the SO community to help you if you supply a jsfiddle.net of what you have so far or a live link? Failing that, the relevant html, css and jQuery.

Comment: Exactlly...I want the absolute position to remain! No succsess....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use some sort of centering, the change in width won't be a problem because they will all be centered correctly. Then all you have to do is position a known-width element that won't change depending on the image.

```
<div class="viewer">
    <img/>
</div>

.viewer{
    text-align: center;
}
.viewer img{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think your best option is to try and work with the fact that each image is a different size. Create a transition effect that enlarges and shrinks your slideshow to fit the size of the image within. Makes for a much smoother, more trendy effect - if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I understand...But my question is...if I have an image with certain width with absolute position,and then I will switch that image with another image with a different width...the image won't have the same position...:-(

Comment: My answer assumes that you forgo the absolute position. I'm actually explaining a pretty common effect used on the web. See the **Image Set** example for Lightbox 2 - http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/